# South 0.8.3 upgrade causes DeserializationError

Tags: django, django-south

I have a Django 1.5.5 project that uses South 0.8.2.  Everything works great -- including migration using South.  When I attempt to upgrade this project to South 0.8.3, I get the following error when I run `python manage.py migrate`:

```
(VBEZ)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64:/vagrant$ python manage.py migrate
Running migrations for django_mailbox:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for django_mailbox.
Installed 3 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Running migrations for djcelery:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for djcelery.
DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'initial_data.json': Invalid model identifier: 'sites.site'
```

**What has happened?**

Here is my `initial_data.json` file:

```
[
  {
    "pk": 1, 
    "model": "sites.site", 
    "fields": {
      "domain": "0.0.0.0:5000", 
      "name": "Project (Development)"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "pk": 2, 
    "model": "sites.site", 
    "fields": {
      "domain": "project-staging.example.com", 
      "name": "Project (Staging)"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "pk": 3, 
    "model": "sites.site", 
    "fields": {
      "domain": "project.example.com", 
      "name": "Project"
    }
  }
]
```

Here is what a successful migration using South 0.8.2 looks like:

```
Running migrations for django_mailbox:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for django_mailbox.
Installed 3 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Running migrations for djcelery:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for djcelery.
Installed 3 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Running migrations for taggit:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for taggit.
Installed 3 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Running migrations for eee_core:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for eee_core.
Installed 3 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Running migrations for core:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for core.
Installed 3 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

Things I have looked at/tried:

- `django-contrib-sites` is in my `INSTALLED_APPS'
- Migration works fine if the `initial_data.json` file is removed.
- If I run migrations individually, they run fine.  Example `python manage.py migrate myapp`.
- I have submitted a ticket: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1324

Thanks.

Comment: same problem, but if i migrate a separate app, it loads initial data.
try: `python manage.py migrate django_mailbox`

Comment: Yes, it does work if I run migrations individually.  But under 0.8.2, I did not have to do this.  This also requires me to know which of my 3rd party apps need to be migrated -- not a good long term solution for maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this a known bug in South 0.8.3: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1320.  Fix is expected in a week or so.

**Update**: South 0.8.4 fixes this bug.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I just started using south, and it was driving me crazy...